# What is a true antonym for "stronger"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The word "stronger" means simply having more strength than, however when saying A is stronger than B, it does not imply that B is not strong just that A has more strength (B is strong but A is stronger). Therefore I am looking for the true antonym for this, in that I would like to say that B has less strength than A but is not necessarily weak. I don't really like "weaker" as an antonym because it implies that the subject is weak, when they may not be.

Eg. Consider the difference between superman and batman; saying superman is stronger than batman seems fine, but saying batman is weaker than superman to me seems to imply that batman is weak, which is not the case since compared to an average person he is very strong, he just has much less strength than superman.

Comment: 'stronger' does not imply strong, just as 'weaker' does not imply weak.

Comment: Anyway there's always "less strong" if you want to steer clear of "weak"

Comment: As you allude to, the terms _stronger_ and _weaker_ are strictly relative. Is Batman weak? Not in any kind of absolute sense. However, strictly compared to Superman, he is. This is true with any superlative. Is our sun small? Certainly not, when compared with any other object in our solar system. However, when compared with other stars that are 100 times larger, it's minuscule. If you don't want to use the term "weaker", you can simply say "less strong", or otherwise clarify your position: _Batman is weaker than Superman, but still strong._ __or__ _Batman is less strong than Superman_.

Comment: @Zack this is great, please change this comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The problem with the superhero example is that both are 'strong', so *stronger* sounds fine but *weaker* doesn't. If you used examples that are both weak (say *Punyman* and *Fatman*, if you'll excuse the choice of rhyme), then it would *sound* odd to say that Punyman is stronger than Fatman, but it would sound fine to say that Fatman is weaker than Punyman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you allude to, the terms stronger and weaker are strictly relative. Is Batman weak? Not in any kind of absolute sense. However, strictly compared to Superman, he is. This is true with any superlative. Is our sun small? Certainly not, when compared with any other object in our solar system. However, when compared with other stars that are 100 times larger, it's minuscule.

If you don't want to use the term "weaker", you can simply say "less strong", or otherwise clarify your position:

> Batman is weaker than Superman, but still strong.

or

> Batman is less strong than Superman.

Answer (score 3):

> Batman is not as strong as superman.

Purists might object that the correct form is

> Batman is not so strong as superman.

but this is rather old-fashioned.

Comment: i’ve never heard that “as strong as” might be objectionable to purists.

Comment: @Jim: Perhaps I'm just showing my age, and all the purists who used to object to it have died. When I was at school, 50 years ago, we were taught that a negative comparison must use _not so...as_ instead of _not as...as_. Looking around on the Internet, it seems that nobody insists on this rule any more.

Comment: I was at school 40 years ago and taught English by a pedantic Cambridge graduate (England, not Massachusetts). He never mentioned any such rule.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Ach, you youngsters...